# flutter place marker on tap with mapbox

Tags: flutter, mapbox, geocoding

I scoured the web, and found no answer specifically for that question for Mapbox and flutter.
I do not have much code, just looking for something.

Comment: Are you using the flutter_map package??

Comment: Yes with mapbox and geocoder

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so flutter's flutter_map plugin actually has an `onTap` function in MapOptions that gives you the location that you tap:

```
FlutterMap(
  options: MapOptions(
    onTap: (position, latLng) {
     // add marker at latLng.latitude and latLng.longitude
  }
)
)
```

Then add a marker at the given point.